# BroadcastReceiver comparing action names

Tags: java, android

I have a broadcast receiver that gets triggered when the battery is low. Notice my if statement. It never goes in.

```
public class ActionReceiverHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("onreceive","in: " + intent.getAction() + " " + Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);

        String actionName = intent.getAction();
        if(actionName.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW)){
            Log.e("detected", "low battery");
        }
    }
}
```

I then decided to add that log real quick to see what the strings returned:

My `intent.getAction()` returns `android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` and my `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` returns `android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW`

Why are the names different? What can I do to ***properly*** fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see here:

[android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW)

> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"

means `BATTERY_OKAY` is `android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW` is original value for `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` constant in Intent class

Comment: Then how come intent.getAction() doesn't return the original value? How should I compare the two?

Comment: @Grimbode: are you using `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Just checked. I am not. Using <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>. I guess this must have been my problem. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: @Grimbode: as i already told  `android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` is constant in Intent class and getAction method return same string which you have passed in action name that's why equal condition is not matching